# how to connect a windows8 app c# with php api

Tags: c#, php, json, api, windows-8

I have this code in which i am trying to connect to a php base api server for a windows8 application.however I am not getting any result knowing that if i try to debug it the url is correct and the variables are set.
i am new in windows8 app and c#, and after several researches this is what connecting to an api server looked like
Any help please

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var username="lucy";
            var password="lucy";

            var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://myURL/login.php?username="+username+"&password="+password) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/json";
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
        }
private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation

        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);


        // Create the post data
        string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postStream).ToString();
        MessageDialog msgDialog1 = new MessageDialog(postData, "bayyanit");
      msgDialog1.ShowAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine(postData);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);


        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
      //  postStream.Close();

        //Start the web request
        try
        {
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponceStreamCallback), request);
        }
    catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog(ex.ToString(), "bayyanit");
            msgDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    void GetResponceStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
        using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog(result, "bayyanit");
            msgDialog.ShowAsync();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Apis are language independent. While you call an API you read the response either in json or xml or any other format irrespective of what language is used to code it.

Comment: @Guns i am new in windows8 apps, looking through my code im expecting a response in json format from the server.what am i missing?

Comment: firstly, did you check if your API is responding well in the designated format?

Comment: yes we checked and it is responding.Actually it is also working on different mobile platforms(ios and android) @Guns

Comment: If I were you, I would debug the api url directly in browser and see if it returns something. So may be you should call the url http://myURL/login.php?username=username&password=password directly in browser, or make an html with a form with method=post and run it in browser and check what it returns.

Comment: i have done this from the beginning.ofcourse it returned a value in the browser @mim

Answer (score 0):

You can build the API with PHP in a single page which receives info via GET or POST and returns JSON object or XML (see [php.net](http://php.net) for the functions you want), what ever your prefer.

after that you're ready to use it with your application via simple HTTP request.

Comment: i have tried this, but i need something more specific concerning my situation